# What subspace of $3 \times 3$ matrices is spanned by a given set?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, symmetric-matrices

For instance, the question asks what subspace of $3\times 3$ matrices is spanned by the set that is the symmetric matrices. Is the question asking me to determine whether the $3\times 3$ symmetric matrices span the nullspace or column space? I'm confused by the wording of the question and what it means by "spans."

Comment: Given a set of vectors $\{v_1, v_2, . . . , v_m\}$ in a vector space $\mathcal{V}$, we define the set of all linear combinations of these vectors to be the Span of $\mathcal{V}$. 

So, let $\mathcal{V}$ be the set of symmetric matrices, i.e. $\mathcal{V}=\{A ∈ M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb{R}) | A^T = A\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The span is considered in the vector space $${\rm Mat}(3, \Bbb R) = \{ \mbox{order $3$ square matrices with real entries}  \}.$$Then $${\rm Sym}(3,\Bbb R) = \{\mbox{order $3$ symmetric matrices with real entries}   \}$$is a vector subspace of ${\rm Mat}(3,\Bbb R)$, and it makes sense to wonder what can be a basis for it. If for $i,j \in \{1,2,3\}$  we let $E_{ij}$ denote the matrix with $1$ in the $(i,j)$ and $0$ everywhere else, you can convince yourself that $$\mathcal{B} = \{ E_{11}, E_{12}, E_{13}, E_{21}, E_{22}, E_{23}, E_{31}, E_{32}, E_{33} \}$$is a basis for ${\rm Mat}(3,\Bbb R)$. Can you pick only a few elements from $\mathcal{B}$ to form a basis for ${\rm Sym}(3,\Bbb R)$? They will already be linearly independent, so you'd have to check that they actually span ${\rm Sym}(3,\Bbb R)$. How many of the $E_{ij}$ are symmetric?

And since ${\rm Sym}(3,\Bbb R)$ is already a vector subspace of ${\rm Mat}(3,\Bbb R)$, the span of ${\rm Sym}(3,\Bbb R)$ is itself.

Answer (score 0):

It is the $6-$dimensional subspace that contains the matrices of the form:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x&a&b\\
a&y&c\\
b&c&z
\end{bmatrix}=
$$
$$
=x\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}+
y\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}+
z\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}+
a\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0\\
1&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}+
$$
$$
+b\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&1\\
0&0&0\\
1&0&0
\end{bmatrix}+
c\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&0&1\\
0&1&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

so it can be spanned by the six matrices in this linear combination that, being linearly independent, are a basis for this subspace.

Answer (score 0):

The space of real matrices $3\text{x} 3$ has dimension $9$ over $\mathbb R$ which correspond to nine entries $a_{ij}$. The subspace generated by the symmetric ones is given by 
$$\lambda\begin{bmatrix}
x&a&b\\
a&y&c\\
b&c&z
\end{bmatrix}+\mu\begin{bmatrix}
x'&a'&b'\\
a'&y'&c'\\
b'&c'&z'
\end{bmatrix}$$ which is obviously still a symmetric matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}
X&A&B\\
A&Y&C\\
B&C&Z
\end{bmatrix}$$ where $X=\lambda x+\mu x'$, etc.

Consequently the asked dimension is equal to $6$ which corresponds to the number of reals $X,Y,Z,A,B,C$ for each new matrix.